# asp.net dynamic forms question

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to figure out a way to create a page that can be used for generic forms.  What i had in mind was someone here at our office would use the obout edit to create html that would look like a form.  This html would be saved to a database.  When the user wanted to fill out the form and mail it, they would click on the correct form retrieval and this html would be put into a label control.  So now the page has a label control on it with some html as the text of the label.  The user could type in the values that they wanted.  So the html might look something like this:

```
<p style="margin: 0px; text-align: center;">
  Quarterly Report of Employees Serverd</p>
<br />
<br />
Employee:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="text" style="width: 300px; height: 22px;" />
<br />
<br />
Address: &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
<input type="text" style="width: 300px; height: 22px;" />
<br />
<br />
<br />
```

The user would type in the input type="text" a value of say John Smith and then type into the address input type as well.

Now I want to grab all this html and mail it off.  I know how to do the mailing portion, but the grabbing the html I'm not getting.  I can grab the html in the label, but the text that that user typed in is not included in that text.  So how do I get that html and the text the user typed in.  Any ideas.

thanks
shannon

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to encode the html to store them securely.
2. Use literal control instead of label or text controls.

Check this [link](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Encode_and_Display_HTML_Securely_in_ASP_NET_2_0.aspx) for the first option.

Thanks :)

and you can use a way like this :

```
<input id="textField" type="text" runat="server"/>
```

C# - Code Behind

```
Mail.Send(textField.Value);
```

and don't forget to use `ValidateRequest="false"` in the header section of asp.net..

:)

Comment: thank you for the response.  I may be misunderstanding you, but i don't believe this will help in that it still won't grab the data input in the Employee or Address input type text.  I've used the encode before and was planning on using it again, i just can't get that input text to be included in what i'm going after.  Any other ideas.

Comment: Sorry actually I misunderstood you :'(

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the Request items to get the submitted values.  If you want to send of an email which substitutes the entered values for the HTML input fields, you'll have to parse out the form HTML to find your input fields:

```
<input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName"
         style="width: 300px; height: 22px;" />
```

And then replace it with

```
Request.Form["firstName"]
```

Notice that the input fields will need identifiers so you can retrieve them from the HTTP request.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you're really going to want to get a little more information into your html - at the very least some `name` attributes on the form elements:

```
Employee: <input type="text" name="employee" />
```

This way, you could create an aspx page like:

```
<%@ Page language="C#" 
         autoeventwireup="true" 
         codebehind="DynamicForm.aspx.cs" 
         inherits="TempWebApp.DynamicForm" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
        <asp:Literal id="m_HtmlForm" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        <asp:Button id="m_SubmitForm" 
                    onclick="SubmitForm_OnClick" 
                    runat="server" 
                    text="Submit" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then in your code you read your html from the database into the `.Text` of the literal control:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace TempWebApp
{
  public partial class DynamicForm : Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      m_HtmlForm.Text = getFormData();
    }

    protected void SubmitForm_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // Just showing we've picked up the form data.
      // You'll also see ViewState and others in here.
      foreach (string key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
      {
        m_HtmlForm.Text += string.Format("<br />Key: <b>{0}</b><br />Value:<br />{1}<br />", key, Request.Form[key]);
      }
    }

    private string getFormData()
    {
      // Excluded for brevity
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously, in your button/postback handler, you would need to ensure you have the original HTML from the database, and then either modify the input elements to add a text attribute to them with the value, or more likely, replace them with the actual values - otherwise you'll have to do lots of additional parsing of the form if your users start saving forms with radio buttons, check boxes, select lists, etc.

Comment: thanks for the help.. this helps a ton.  I'd mark it with an up but i don't have enough points yet.  Again, thank you.
Shannon

Comment: No probs - you should be able to upvote now, and you can always accept an answer too ;)